# How to copy docker logs from a running container

Tags: docker

docker logs are present in the following log file as mentioned below

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' mycontainer
    /var/lib/docker/containers/095110b921176a36ea93e216c36a9876c2ccdda0fbee285920156d32fc2b8010/095110b921176a36ea93e216c36a9876c2ccdda0fbee285920156d32fc2b8010-json.log
```

But I am unable to copy using the following command

```
docker cp mycontainer:`docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' mycontainer` .
Error response from daemon: lstat /var/lib/docker/overlay/b55ca4183cde8b0b8bb696be72e89d147a61cfd2a24d501305d16b598e5bca40/merged/var/lib/docker/containers/095110b921176a36ea93e216c36a9876c2ccdda0fbee285920156d32fc2b8010/095110b921176a36ea93e216c36a9876c2ccdda0fbee285920156d32fc2b8010-json.log: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

The given path is on the docker host, not in the container.
A simple `cp` is enough:

```
cp `docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' mycontainer` .
```